# AppEngine API integration testing with Authorization

Tags: python, google-app-engine, authentication, authorization, integration-testing

I have a web app/api backend that requires a Google Account, and an approved one in order to access. I manage my users within the app, but was wondering if there's a way for me to run integration tests? Naturally whenever I run the POST/PUT/DELETE/GET requests, they return 403 Forbidden, because well... I'm not authorizing to post them! Is there a method I can use to simulate a google account with a specific email? Or would I have to disable the `login: required` in my App.yaml every time I wanted to run an integration test?

Comment: Are you using GAE's testbed for testing?

Comment: I'm trying to test using the http requests, and understood testbed to be for unit testing instead of integration testing?

Comment: I think you can do everything you need with testbed and [webtest](https://webtest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).  I test my API calls that way.